# I'm trying to update the row values in MUI datagrid, i'm using processRowUpdate property.But, I'm only getting recent updated cell value only

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Here **Skills ** will have the array of objects which includes the values Which I'm updating.

const handleProcessRowUpdate = (newRow, oldRow) => {
console.log("update called", newRow, oldRow);

```
let skills = assignedskillList;

let result = skills.map((item) => {
  if (item.skill_id == params.skill_id) {
    console.log("ids", params.skill_id, item.skill_id);


    if (item.skill_level !== newRow.skill_level) {
      item.skill_level = newRow.skill_level;
    }
    if ((item.target_level = newRow.target_level)) {
      item.target_level = newRow.target_level;
    }
    console.log("idsss", item.skill_level, item.target_level);  // here for first column edit //I'm getting current edited value only, for the second col edit getting only second column //value.the first value is resetting

  }
  setUpdatedVal(result);  //I'm setting this in a new array to use this for post to API
  return item;
});
```

tried onCellEdit commit , but, thats not worked. any other solutions ?

or correct me if I'm setting the value wrongly.

Thanks In advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found it.

Hope it might be helpful for someone in future

instead of updating the value inside the map. I've just defined a result array outside and assigned the map to that, Now I can get all updated values..

Thank you...